# OnsenUI ons-bottom-toolbar align

Tags: onsen-ui

Why this code is right only for "ons-toolbar"

```
 <ons-bottom-toolbar>
  <div class="left">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-android-share-alt"></ons-icon>
  </div>
</ons-bottom-toolbar>
```

How can i do horizontal align without CSS?

Comment: Hi Евгений Гедройц, could you be a little more specific for your question?
How does it not working as expected?
I cannot see clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @TrtshenChaw not working classes: left(in my example), right, center. This is wrong onsenui for my opinion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ons-row and ons-col for layout. https://onsen.io/reference/ons-col.html

For example, if you want the left to be 30% and the middle to be 50% and the right to be 20% you can do something like this:

```
<ons-row>
   <ons-col width="30%"> Left </ons-col>
   <ons-col width="50%"> Middle </ons-col>
   <ons-col width="20%"> Right </ons-col>
</ons-row>
```